Shaka-Player - Get DASH manifest periods and current period
I'm currently using shaka-player v4.10.4 and I would like to know how is it possible to get the list of periods contained in the DASH manifest and also get the current period played by the player. Periods infos are not available through the Manifest interface
I would like to access the period id, start and duration properties but I was not able to find anything to retrieve these info ...
Thanks for your help
